# using awk to extract and split

Tags: string, bash, sed, awk, strip

i am trying to extract a substring with awk from a command answer in bash

example output line:  **abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq**

getting the second part is easy by

```
echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | awk '{print $2}'
```

but i only need the last part substring "opq" and didn't find a way to let awk run twice over the string, when i pass the result from above to a var and use this var for second awk i get an error because the string is a path and therefore a Directory. too i didn't get sed to work with the same error when used on a stored var with the string and i did not manage to pass first substring to second awk or sed. weird?

this would do the Job if not first awk would print out instead of passing to second awk

```
echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"_" '{print $3}'
```

works neither

```
echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | awk '{$2}' | awk -F"_" '{print $3}'
```

how can i pass it right to secondly strip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | awk -F_ '{ print $NF}'
opq
```

`NF` is a built-in variable that stores number of fields. When you split the line with `_` and tell `awk` to print `$NF` you will print the last field.

However, you might not always need last part of the string. In that case you can use `substr` function in `awk`.

Using same example, you can do:

```
$ echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | awk ' { print substr($2,9) }'
opq
```

`substr` function takes 3 arguments, the third being optional. First argument is the string in question. Second argument is the starting point and third (optional) argument is the length you want to capture. If you don't provide it then by default it will capture everything until the end of string.

Comment: thanks again for diggin in deeper and providing compressed usage guide, i like the substr version, while in this special case i am not always shure of the (because returned string from other function) string length while i am shure it will be always the last part

Comment: for others now needing the second (or other) last substring in this solution would be: `echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | awk -F_  '{print $(NF-1)}'` while i do not know by now how to Count from beginning of the string?

Comment: @peet You can always use `for loop` and do `for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { printf $i FS } print NF`

Answer (score 2):

You can also make of parameter substitution in bash:

```
var="abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq";
echo ${var##*_};
```

returns

```
opq
```

Comment: Nice and simple one! In this case using `echo ... | awk ...` is an overkill.

Comment: echo was only to test output, if a var is already set this is very simple solution, in my exact case the input of awk is the return of another function and using a var was only my workaround because not getting passed first stripped string to second awk - but for existing var a cool way yes. (while i will have to [and will do] read about this solution to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq | grep -Po '[^_]+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*_//' <<<"abc_def_ghi jkl_lmn_opq"
```

Comment: workin while i do not get it right. s is separating switch, second is the separator, but why does it return last substring without third argument - default behaviour?

Comment: @peet `.*` means find zero or more of any single character. As the regexp engine is *greedy* it zips to the end of the string. It then has to backtrack till it finds a `_`. So this finds the last `_` in the string and then removes all characters and the last `_` leaving the desired result. Remember the string is everything from `abc` to `opq`.

Comment: thanks for explaination, what would i use to get the second last substring?